# Concurrence between 2 qubits of tripartite system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, density-operator

If we consider a tripartite system (say of 3 qubits) described by density matrix $\rho_{ABC}$, does the concurrence $C(\rho_{BC})$ still accurately measure the entanglement between subsystems B and C? Using the notation that $\rho_{BC} = Tr_A(\rho_{ABC})$ and so describes the total BC subsystem.

I'm using the concurrence, defined as $$C(\rho) = \text{max}(0, \lambda_1-\lambda_2-\lambda_3-\lambda_4) $$

where $\lambda_i$'s are the ordered eigenvalues of the matrix $R=\sqrt{\sqrt{\rho}\rho'\sqrt{\rho}}$ and $\rho'= (\sigma_y \otimes \sigma_y)\rho^*(\sigma_y \otimes \sigma_y)$ is the spin-flipped density matrix.

(Sorry, if this is a naïve question.)

Comment: Isn't that the point of the concurrence - to measure entanglement between two qubits?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch After some more thought, I think what I'm really asking is: suppose the partial trace of a pure state results in a mixed quantum state between the 2 remaining qubits, meaning there is some entanglement between system A and the rest. Does the concurrence still work as a measure to calculate entanglement between the remaining systems, as now the density matrix is mixed? or does it only work for a bipartite pure state? I assume that it describes the same thing in both cases.